# Switching Jobs - What should I do with 401k? Roll to IRA? Transfer to new 401k? Leave it?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, roth-ira

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Started new job. Rollover previous employer 401k to new 401k, IRA or Roth IRA?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/842/started-new-job-rollover-previous-employer-401k-to-new-401k-ira-or-roth-ira)

I'm leaving my current employer next week and have about $10k in a 401k plan. What is best to do with this?

Transfer to my new employers 401k? Any penalties there?
Roll into a traditional IRA?

I guess also: what really is the pros/cons of traditional IRA vs 401k? Thanks!

Comment: Lets get some details.  Where is you current 401K?  What is it invested in?  What are the costs for the current plan?  What does the new employer offer?  How much does that cost?