# Should you always rollover a 401k to a personal IRA after leaving a company?

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement

As far as I know, all 401ks charge recurring fees to the employees. Some even charge percentage fees based on your balance.  This is on top of the fund fees you'd have to pay for Fidelity/Vanguard/etc funds.

Also, as far as I know, personal IRAs at places like Fidelity and Vanguard do NOT charge recurring fees.

Isn't it always better to roll over your 401k at a company you left into your own personal IRA where you have no fees, and can invest in whatever funds you want?

I'm trying to think if there are any advantages to rolling over a 401k into a new company's 401k, or leaving it in the old company's 401k account...

Comment: I guess this question is very related: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/842/started-new-job-rollover-previous-employer-401k-to-new-401k-ira-or-roth-ira?rq=1 (the answers get at what I'm asking). I'm fine with 'closing as dup' if others agree. I'd prefer an unequivocal 'You should always go to IRA in the situation you described'.

Comment: I was once in a state plan (non-401k) that precluded rejoining after a rollover. Not sure if that's a legal restriction on 401(k)s, though.

Comment: I have been in multiple 401k plans where there is no fee if you're above a certain balance. Also, the 401ks usually have access to medallion funds (funds with really low fees) that you wouldn't have access to in your ira unless you have a certain amount invested

Comment: The premise of your first paragraph is false. Fees are plan-dependent. It's very possible to have a 401k that offers better options than an IRA you can roll into.

Comment: See also the answers to [Why would you not want to rollover a previous employers 401k when changing jobs](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/22829/5760).

Comment: @Todd I guess I'm assuming that the options of "IRA you can roll into" includes the best IRAs (fee-wise) that exist, such as Fidelity. Basically you are restricted to your 401k choice, but unrestricted to your IRA choice, so you should always choose lowest cost IRA (which should always beat or meet fees on 401k).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm trying to think if there are any advantages to rolling over a 401k
>   into a new company's 401k, or leaving it in the old company's 401k
>   account...

Advantages of 401k (either the old one or the new one):

1. (In the company where you're currently employed) you can take a loan from your 401k.
2. Depending on the plan choices you may have funds with much lower expense ratios in 401k than are available to retail investors (IRA).
3. <s><sub>*There are no [RMD (Required Minimum Distributions)](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Retirement-Plans-FAQs-regarding-Required-Minimum-Distributions) from 401k.*</sub></s>
4. 401k balance doesn't affect the IRA->ROTH conversion ([the IRA loophole](http://littleadvisor.wordpress.com/2013/11/06/the-roth-ira-loophole-retirement-planning-for-high-earners/)).
5. You can start withdrawals from 401k at the age of 55, IRA - at the age of 60.

Disadvantages, as you mentioned, are fees and plan choices' limitations. The decision is yours, but it's not straight-forward. You'll need to decide which trade-offs to make.

Comment: (1) this is a good reason to move to the new company 401(k), correct? (3) ? Only while still working, once you leave the company, RMDs kick in at 70.5. (4) Nice shameless plug, and an article worth a read. (5) only if you separate from the company after 55, careful if you leave any younger.

Comment: +1 for (4); there is a large percentage of people who are above the Roth IRA contribution income limit, and this is the only way to contribute. Also, another advantage: 401(k)s are better protected from bankruptcy and debtors than IRAs.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer has already commented on statement #3 about RMDs which I also believe is incorrect; 401k plans _do_ have RMDs. I will add the point that if there are several 401k plans, it is necessary to take an RMD from each of them in the proper amount for each plan (ditto for 403b plans etc). In contrast, _all_ the (non-inherited) IRA balances are lumped together in determining the RMD, and the RMD amount can be taken from _any_ combination of plans that the owner chooses; it is not necessary to take the appropriate amount from each IRA account as it is with 401k plans.

Comment: And. Roth 401(k) has RMDs as well, while the Roth IRA avoids this.

Comment: I stand corrected, I was sure 401ks don't have RMD

Comment: Consider, if we are caught in these errors, what chance does the average person have? A convoluted, incomprehensible, tax code. And one that constantly has changes to track, and adjust your strategy to maneuver around.

Comment: @Joe Unfortunately most of the Americans don't know any other way, for them all this is natural. When most of the population has never been abroad, it is hard to convince them that their country isn't perfect.