# Rollover 401k to IRA or another 401k in the future

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, retirement

I have a 401k from my previous employer but currently working at a contract-to-hire position and have no 401k. Would it be a better idea to roll the 401k into an IRA or wait until I have another 401k and roll into that? I also have a Roth IRA and was curious if a non-Roth 401k can be rolled into a Roth IRA.

Comment: See https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/842/started-new-job-rollover-previous-employer-401k-to-new-401k-ira-or-roth-ira