# Quitting working - where to put 401k money?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira

My spouse is considering becoming a stay-at-home parent. They currently work and have a 401k. If they do leave their job, and want to rollover the 401k, what's the best investment vehicle to choose? Is a traditional IRA the right answer?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/842/started-new-job-rollover-previous-employer-401k-to-new-401k-ira-or-roth-ira) help? I realize this refers to starting a new job as well but the rest applies.

Comment: Referenced question looks super helpful. Thank you.